# MySQL combining 2 queries

Tags: mysql

Can someone please help me combine the 2 queries below?  The goal is to create Speaker and Organizer variables in php (also below).  Thanks!

```
$query= "
SELECT srMeet.mOrg, srMeet.mSpeaker, users.uID, users.uFirst, users.uLast
FROM srMeet 
INNER JOIN users
ON users.uID = srMeet.mSpeaker";

$query= "
SELECT srMeet.mOrg, srMeet.mSpeaker, users.uID, users.uFirst, users.uLast
FROM srMeet 
INNER JOIN users
ON users.uID = srMeet.mOrg";


$Speaker = $row['uFirst'] . "&nbsp;" . $row['uLast'];

$Organizer = $row['uFirst'] . "&nbsp;" . $row['uLast'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that a meet has a single speaker and a single organizer you could use a join to get the details for a meet in a single row.

```
$query= "SELECT srMeet.mOrg, 
            srMeet.mSpeaker, 
            UserSpeaker.uID AS SpeakerUid, 
            UserSpeaker.uFirst AS SpeakerFirst, 
            UserSpeaker.uLast AS SpeakerLast, 
            UserOrganizer.uID AS OrganizerUid, 
            UserOrganizer.uFirst AS OrganizerFirst, 
            UserOrganizer.uLast AS OrganizerLast
        FROM srMeet 
        INNER JOIN users UserSpeaker
        ON UserSpeaker.uID = srMeet.mSpeaker
        INNER JOIN users UserOrganizer
        ON UserOrganizer.uID = srMeet.mOrg";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join the same table multiple times in a query and give them aliases using `AS`. The `AS` keyword is actually optional but I always include it as a note to myself.

The `INNER JOIN`s here mean that each meeting must have both an organizer and a speaker. If there's a chance of having a meeting without an organizer or a speaker, you might want to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s and do some thing to handle NULL values.

```
SELECT CONCAT(s.uFirst, '&nbsp;', s.uLast) AS speaker, 
  CONCAT(o.uFirst, '&nbsp;', o.uLast) AS organizer
FROM srMeet 
INNER JOIN users AS s
ON users.uID = srMeet.mSpeaker
INNER JOIN users AS o
ON users.uID = srMeet.mOrg;


$Speaker = $row['speaker'];

$Organizer = $row['organizer'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use **[UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)**

```
$query= "
SELECT srMeet.mOrg, srMeet.mSpeaker, users.uID, users.uFirst, users.uLast
FROM srMeet 
INNER JOIN users
ON users.uID = srMeet.mSpeaker
UNION
SELECT srMeet.mOrg, srMeet.mSpeaker, users.uID, users.uFirst, users.uLast
FROM srMeet 
INNER JOIN users
ON users.uID = srMeet.mOrg"
```

Comment: But how does that help get the two separate values I need?  Previously, I used something like "users.uFirst AS 'SpeakerFN'", but I am not sure how to do it here.